# SVN update command to rediscover conflicts

Tags: bash, svn, command-line, meld

I did an `svn update` from the command line on a fairly old sandbox with a few local changes. There were conflicts detected, so I saw the usual output:

```
Conflict discovered in 'file.cpp'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options: p
```

I hadn't set up my svn command line options on this computer, so my preferred method of launching `meld` to resolve the conflict wasn't available. Therefore I chose to postpone the conflict until I had meld set up.

I then set up `meld`, using a similar procedure to [the one shown here](http://codingundertheinfluence.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/using-meld-as-your-external-diff3.html).

Now, doing another `svn update` does not rediscover the conflict and therefore does not give me the option to launch meld. I only get an "`At revision ...`" shown. Is there a way to get the "`Conflict discovered in ...`" line again? Or is there a command to launch the 3-way meld resolver?

Comment: @Clement Ray: Thanks, but I don't want a list of the current conflicts, I can do that with `svn status`. What I am after is way of launching the interactive conflict resolver, after I am already in a state of conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [it's documentation](http://meldmerge.org/help/resolving-conflicts.html) *meld* can be used as a git merge helper. A [git merge helper](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html) is called like this:

> When git mergetool is invoked with this tool (either through the -t or
>   --tool option or the merge.tool configuration variable) the configured command line will be invoked with $BASE set to the name of a temporary
>   file containing the common base for the merge, if available; $LOCAL
>   set to the name of a temporary file containing the contents of the
>   file on the current branch; $REMOTE set to the name of a temporary
>   file containing the contents of the file to be merged, and $MERGED set
>   to the name of the file to which the merge tool should write the
>   result of the merge resolution.

So at least you can run it like this:

```
export BASE=some_file.r123
export LOCAL=some_file.mine
export REMOTE=some_file.r124
export MERGED=some_file
meld
```

I don't know whether this is the same as running it with [its three-file syntax](http://meldmerge.org/help/command-line.html): `meld some_file.r123 some_file.mine some_file.r124`.

Comment: Thanks, AndreKR, this is helpful. I was trying to figure out how to launch `meld` as a 3-way resolver manually using the `.mine`, `.rX` and `.rY` files that svn creates, and this is the answer. It does not answer how to launch it automatically, but I am starting to think that this may not be possible. I will keep searching for a bit, but if it does turn out to be impossible then I will accept yours as the best solution :-)

Comment: However, if you find a "real answer" (how to invoke that dialog again), you should answer your own question and mark that one accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Follow  up @AndreKR

- How to resolve postponed conflict with Meld installed

Because you have (after postponing) 3 temp-files for every file-in-conflict (*.MY, *.THEIR, *.BASE) and Meld can accept up to three filenames as parameters for file-diff, you just run by hand `meld MY BASE THEIR`, edit MY files in order to get needed result, save it, and, for closing merge-conflict, use after it `svn resolve --accept 'my-full FILENAME'` (accoring to `svn help resolve` "the --accept option is currently required"  and `svn resolve` is also a must all changes was done in MY file)

- How to use Meld as merger-differ forever

`[helpers]` section in config file: `diff-cmd`, `diff3-cmd` and `merge-tool-cmd` keys will get common value -  `meld` (maybe with path, but without parameters). You'll get small trouble with merge-tool, because "...Subversion will pass 4 arguments to the specified command" and Meld can accept only 3, but mentioned by you blog-post contain workaround for this headache